# Why does my mixed effects model fail to converge when fixed effects are added? How do I solve this problem?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, convergence, fixed-effects-model

I'm running a study in which participants rate the politeness of two different types of smiles (two levels: rewarding and affiliative) presented in three different situational contexts (three levels: negative, enjoyable, polite). This is within-subjects. I have 85 participants who complete 36 trials each.

As per Meteyard & Davies (2020), I have tried to specify the parsimonious random effects for my model before adding any fixed effects to the model. After running the model simplification process suggested by Bates et al (2015), I get this random effects structure:

```
summary(PolModSimp5 <- 
lmer(Response ~ (1 + smileType + contextCat | Participant.Private.ID) + (1 | identity), data = PolitenessData))
```

This model converges with no issues. However, when I then add fixed effects to the model (see below)...

```
summary(PolMod <- 
lmer(Response ~ smileType*contextCat + (1 + smileType + contextCat | Participant.Private.ID) + (1 | identity), data = PolitenessData))
```

I get the classic warning that the model failed to converge:

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
> Warning: Model failed to converge with 1 negative eigenvalue: -1.6e+01

First of all, I'm wondering why this happens? Surely my random effects structure isn't overfitted if the model converges without fixed effects added?

Second, how might you suggest I solve this problem?

Any advice would be hugely appreciated! Thank you!